# Multinomial Probability Model with Correlation between random variables

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to create a p.m.f. for a Multinomial distribution where the variables are correlated with one another. Let $k$ index the random variables $x$ and their probabilities $p$. There are to be $n$ draws or trials. $\vec{p}$ is a $1$ by $k$ vector of $p_{k}$ and $\vec{x}$ is a $1$ by $k$ vector of $x_{k}$.

I know the p.m.f. for a Multinomial distribution is $n!\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{p_{i}^{x_{i}}}{x_{i}!}$ . I also know that the I need to create a $k$ by $k$ covariance matrix, call it $A$, where $Cov(x_{i},x_{j}) = -np_{i}p_{j}$ for all $i,j$. My question is, how do I incorporate the covariance matrix into the Multinomial p.m.f. to find the correct probabilities? Can I simply multiply $\vec{p} \cdot A $, which will result in a $1$ by $k$ vector? Is this the correct probability? I'm really stuck at this part.

Comment: I'd bootstrap, but that is me.  If they are correlated then a lag-plot should show it.  That means that a table showing the value drawn at time i vs. i+1 should capture a fair bit of the physics.  You should know how many lags are relevant to the autocorrelation.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably end up just using monte carlo on the entire system, but wanted to see if there was a closed form solution first

Comment: Benjamin Franklin says that necessity is the mother of invention, but laziness is the father.  There is a ceiling of difficulty beyond which making the computer do the heavy lifting has better returns than the elegant derivations.  To be sure it is a moving ceiling but the motion is slow and discontinuous.  Fractalesque perhaps?

Comment: How long until physicists realize this and become engineers lol